# Issue on importing Dataframe into SQL Server with d6tstack.utils library of Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am having problems with the function d6tstack.utils.pd_to_mssql() when I want to import the Dataframe into Microsoft SQL Server database with Python3. The name of SQL Table is fxxProduktKatalogDE. I found that the name in function should be written lowercase and so I did. But I get the error as the Table does not exists. The table is there in database. I also tried to write in the table name the name exactly as in database but the same error happens.

Here the Code and the error

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJX8u.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3zFo.png)

Thank you in advance !